# how to sort a string in C++ using sort function

Tags: string, sorting

Why I'm getting error in this code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1= "deepak";
    cout << s1 << endl;
    string s2= sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    cout << s2 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

ERROR :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nvla.png)

main.cpp:10:20: error: conversion from 'void' to non-scalar type 'std::string'
{aka 'std""__cxx11::basic_string,char>'} requested

Answer (score 0):

The sort function sorts elements in a range, but it does not return the sorted string. You can sort s1 in-place:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1= "deepak";
    cout << s1 << endl;
    sort(s1.begin(), s1.end());
    cout << s1 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

if you want to return a sorted string:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

string sortString(string s) {
    string sortedString = s;
    sort(sortedString.begin(), sortedString.end());
    return sortedString;
}

int main()
{
    string s1= "deepak";
    cout << s1 << endl;
    string sortedS1 = sortString(s1);
    cout << sortedS1 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the second version create *three* new strings? One when calling the function, one for your extra variable, and one when returning?

Comment: Yes, the second version of the code creates three strings:

The original string passed as an argument to the ***sortString*** function.
A copy of the original string created inside the sortString function.
The sorted string that is returned by the sortString function.
The creation of multiple strings can increase the memory usage and slow down the performance. If you want to avoid creating multiple strings, you can sort the original string passed as an argument in place, and return a reference to the original string:

Comment: ```#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

string& sortString(string &s) {
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    string s1= "deepak";
    cout << s1 << endl;
    string &sortedS1 = sortString(s1);
    cout << sortedS1 << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```